# Laravel query builder not using variable from get method

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, laravel-query-builder

I have this function in one of my controller.

```
public function tourList($country, $category)
{
    $tour = Tour::whereHas('country', function($q) {
                    $q->where('name','=', $country);
                })
                ->whereHas('category', function($r) {
                    $r->where('name','=', $category);
                })
                ->get();

    return view('tour-list.blade.php')->withTour('$tour');
}
```

Though have passed two variables from get method. But i am getting error of

```
Undefined variable: country
```

Comment: Show me the routes path @zacharyDale

Comment: Route::get('tour/{country}/{categpry}', ['as' => 'tour.list', 'uses' => 'PublicController@tourList']);

Comment: Change '$tour' to $tour as we have to pass variable in withTour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `use` in anonymous function so your query willl be  as:

```
$tour = Tour::whereHas('country', function($q) use($country) {
                $q->where('name','=', $country);
            })
            ->whereHas('category', function($r) use($category) {
                $r->where('name','=', $category);
            })
            ->get();
```

[Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)